# how to always show headers in RowsFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, leanback

I'm trying to create an Android tv application similar to the Youtube application. and I am using the [Sofa](https://github.com/dextorer/Sofa) library to do that. Now the problem comes when I am trying to show the headers for individual items in the `RowsFragment` even when the `RowsFragment` doesn't have a focus. following is the code for loading the dataset into browseFragment

```
private void loadRowsCustom() {
        adapter = new ArrayObjectAdapter();

        int split = 3;
        int rowsFragmentCount = videoList.size() / split + (videoList.size() % split != 0 ? 1 : 0);

        for (int i = 0; i < rowsFragmentCount; i++) {

            ListRowPresenter lrp = new ListRowPresenter(FocusHighlight.ZOOM_FACTOR_LARGE);
            ArrayObjectAdapter rowsAdapter = new ArrayObjectAdapter(lrp);

            String category = "Category";

            for (int j = 0; j < split && (i * split + j) < videoList.size(); j++) {
                Video[] videos = videoList.get(i * split + j);
                ArrayObjectAdapter rowCollAdapter = new ArrayObjectAdapter(new VideoPresenter());
                rowCollAdapter.addAll(0, Arrays.asList(videos));
                ListRow row = new ListRow(new HeaderItem(videos[0].category),rowCollAdapter);
                rowsAdapter.add(row);
                category = videos[0].category;
            }

            ArrayObjectAdapter fragmentAdapter = new ArrayObjectAdapter();
            RowsSupportFragment rowsSupportFragment = new RowsSupportFragment();
            rowsSupportFragment.setAdapter(rowsAdapter);
            rowsSupportFragment.enableRowScaling(false);
            fragmentAdapter.add(rowsSupportFragment);
            adapter.add(new ListRow(new HeaderItem(category), fragmentAdapter));
        }

        browseSupportFragment.setAdapter(adapter);
        browseSupportFragment.setHeadersState(BrowseSupportFragment.HEADERS_ENABLED);
        browseSupportFragment.setOnSearchClickedListener(searchClickListener);
        browseSupportFragment.setOnItemViewClickedListener(browseClickListener);
        browseSupportFragment.setTitle("Google Videos");
    }
```

The required and the current implementation is described as in the screenshots below:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Mayur Kaul already mentioned, u just need to call

```
mRowsFragment.setExpand(true)
```

But in this case everytime when `onAttachedToWindow(...)` method would be called (see `android.support.v17.leanback.app.RowsFragment`  - `ItemBridgeAdapter.AdapterListener mBridgeAdapterListener`), your header titles anyway would be hidden.

So final solution, witch worked for me it's just simply override `setExpand()` method in your RowsFragment implementation like below:

```
@Override
    public void setExpand(boolean expand) {
        super.setExpand(true);
    }
```

Comment: For those whose eyes glazed over this like mine did before reading it properly - this isn't just a pointless override, `true` is always passed to the superclass' `setExpand` method. This should be marked as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

For those who are facing a similar problem, i finally managed to find a hack which will give the desired results. But for that you might need to get the source of `BrowseSupportFragment` or  in [Sofa](https://github.com/dextorer/Sofa) and modify the following line of code. I know its a bit of hack, but it get's the desired output.

For BrowseFragment: `Notice the mRowsFragment.setExpand(true)`

```
private void showHeaders(boolean show) {
        if (DEBUG) Log.v(TAG, "showHeaders " + show);
        mHeadersFragment.setHeadersEnabled(show);
        setHeadersOnScreen(show);
        setRowsAlignedLeft(!show);
        if (mRowsFragment != null) {
            mRowsFragment.setExpand(true);
        } else if (mCurrentFragment != null && mCurrentFragment instanceof RowsFragment) {
            ((RowsFragment) mCurrentFragment).setExpand(true);
        }
    }
```

and same goes for the `BrowseSupportFragment` as well

```
private void showHeaders(boolean show) {
        if (DEBUG) Log.v(TAG, "showHeaders " + show);
        mHeadersSupportFragment.setHeadersEnabled(show);
        setHeadersOnScreen(show);
        setRowsAlignedLeft(!show);
        if (mRowsSupportFragment != null) {
            mRowsSupportFragment.setExpand(true);
        } else if (mCurrentFragment != null && mCurrentFragment instanceof RowsSupportFragment) {
            ((RowsSupportFragment) mCurrentFragment).setExpand(true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: how you have solved this problem ? please can u explain because i want to do similar thing in my TV app.

Comment: It's not working in my case.. Can you put your code on Github?

Comment: as the method is package-private and not accessible, how can we use it?