# How to make always visible headers of rows in RowsFragment

Tags: android-fragments, android-tv, leanback

Here is what i have now.

[image]

Simply my RowsFragment is look like this,

```
public static class SampleFragmentB extends RowsFragment {
        private final ArrayObjectAdapter mRowsAdapter;

        public SampleFragmentB() {
            mRowsAdapter = new ArrayObjectAdapter(new ShadowRowPresenterSelector());

            setAdapter(mRowsAdapter);
            setOnItemViewClickedListener(new OnItemViewClickedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClicked(
                        Presenter.ViewHolder itemViewHolder,
                        Object item,
                        RowPresenter.ViewHolder rowViewHolder,
                        Row row) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Implement click handler", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            createRows();
            getMainFragmentAdapter().getFragmentHost().notifyDataReady(getMainFragmentAdapter());
        }

        private void createRows() {
                String json = Utils.inputStreamToString(getResources().openRawResource(
                        R.raw.page_row_example));
                CardRow[] rows = new Gson().fromJson(json, CardRow[].class);
                for (CardRow row : rows) {
                    mRowsAdapter.add(createCardRow(row));
                }
        }

        private Row createCardRow(CardRow cardRow) {
            PresenterSelector presenterSelector = new CardPresenterSelector(getActivity());
            ArrayObjectAdapter adapter = new ArrayObjectAdapter(presenterSelector);
            for (Card card : cardRow.getCards()) {
                adapter.add(card);
            }

            HeaderItem headerItem = new HeaderItem(cardRow.getTitle());
            return new CardListRow(headerItem, adapter, cardRow);
        }
    }
```

This is what i exactly want to do,

[image]

So I want to make always visible Header of each row without selecting into or focusing into RowsFragment. I'am using leanback v24 to add multiple rows into each header item.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check the [Sofa](https://github.com/dextorer/Sofa) library for Android TV that extends the [Leanback library](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v17-leanback) capabilities by offering a set of more powerful features. In `BrowseSupportFragment`, `mRowsFragment.setExpand` should be `true`. Additional reference: [how to always show headers in RowsFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35151717/how-to-always-show-headers-in-rowsfragment)

Comment: thanks for your help, but am not allowed Sofa in this project. If there is not any other solutions, i may have to use it.. Thanks for answering.